# rev and cut commands run through a pipe-line never returns

Tags: linux, bash

I can't figure out why this command never returns.

`echo "a_b_c_d_e_f_g" | rev | cut -d_ -f2-`

It looks to me that one of the commands is waiting for EOF.

I am using Cent-OS. `rev` is `/usr/bin/rev` and `cut` is `/usr/bin/cut`

Comment: This command returns `f_e_d_c_b_a` on CentOS 7.4.

Comment: @pgngp That's odd.  My dist is CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708. And, I am using ssh with X redirected (I don't think this matters, though).

Comment: Mine is `7.4.1708` as well.

Comment: Add output of `type rev cut` to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have CentOS with me so couldn't test your command(though it worked for me on Linux). As a workaround if you would like you could try following then.

```
echo "a_b_c_d_e_f_g" | awk -F"_" '{for(i=(NF-1);i>0;i--){val=val?val OFS $i:$i};print val;val=""}' OFS="_"
```

Output will be as follows.

```
f_e_d_c_b_a
```

Comment: This command works! But, still why the rev | cut does not end?

Comment: @rkioji, as I already mentioned I don't have centOS with me but this worked for me on LINUX. Also try first running only `echo ..... | rev` part alone see if that itself is coming or not?